# How do I change the schema of a postgres data source in strongloop?

Tags: postgresql, schema, loopbackjs, strongloop

I'm trying to tell strongloop that my gallery table has moved to the products schema. Adding it to the model definition in `common/models/gallery.json` seemingly has no effect.  New to strongloop. What am I doing wrong?

My current schema.  `"schema": "products"` is the only thing added.

```
{
  "name": "gallery",
  "plural": "galleries",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true,
    "schema": "products"
  },
  "properties": {
    "id": {
      "type": "number"
    },
    "name": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },
    "description": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "uuid": {
      "type": "uuid"
    },
    "test": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "order": {
      "type": "number"
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {},
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}
```

uuid is a placeholder

Answer (score 0):

Answer is here: https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/PostgreSQL+connector

Correct options value:

```
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true,
    "postgresql": {
      "schema": "products"
    }
  }
```